# how to show all the Object in static ion-segment

Tags: angular, ionic2, segment

I am trying to have one static button in segment and remaining are dynamic my dynamic part is working but my static segment button is not showing all the product

here is my .html file

```
<ion-content >

    <ion-segment [(ngModel)]="kmart" color="primary">
        <ion-segment-button value="All">
          All
        </ion-segment-button>
        <ion-segment-button *ngFor="let tabName of buttonName" value={{tabName.product_type}}>
          {{tabName.product_type}}
        </ion-segment-button>
  </ion-segment>

  <div [ngSwitch]="kmart" *ngFor = "let demo of demoObj">
  <ion-list *ngSwitchCase="All">
        <ion-item>
          {{demo.name}}
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
    <ion-list *ngSwitchCase="demo.product_type">
        <ion-item>
          {{demo.name}}
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
</div>

</ion-content>
```

here is my .ts file

```
demoObj = [ {"product_id": "52","name": "Apple - Fuji","product_type": "Fruits"},
              {"product_id": "53","name": "bana - Fuji","product_type": "Fruits"},
              {"product_id": "54","name": "beetroot - Fuji","product_type": "Vegitables"},
              {"product_id": "55","name": "beens - Fuji","product_type": "Vegitables"},
              {"product_id": "56","name": "mango - Fuji","product_type": "Fruits"}
            ];
  buttonName = [{"product_type": "Fruits"},{"product_type": "Vegitables"}];
```

**Question:**

here at first time am able to display all the products but after switching  to another segments and then i am come to 'All' segment I am not able to display any one can find any mistake.

Comment: do you get any error the second time? what happens?

Comment: All is a string right?

Comment: no errors i am not sure i think that `value='All'` and `*ngSwitchCase="All"` is not matching probably that was causing error that was my assumsun

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I think that value='All' and *ngSwitchCase="All" is not matching
>   probably that was causing error

You are right in your assumption. In order to set switch case as string literal you need to give single quotes within the double quotes.

```
 <ion-list *ngSwitchCase="'All'">
        <ion-item>
          {{demo.name}}
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
```